# How to connect a frequency inverter to my motor?

Tags: motor, inverter

Hi a have a multitool machine running a 3 phase, 380V motor with two speeds through a switch (0,37 Kw and 0,51 Kw). Since i only have 220v at home a bought a frequency converter, that can do that. 
The inverter i bought is a ["FR-S520SE 0,75K"](http://datasheet.octopart.com/FR-S520SE-0.75K-EC-Mitsubishi-datasheet-506793.pdf) (the datasheet into the link)

The wiring of the motors looks like this :
[image]
I am confused how to connect the motor to my inverter ?, since i have - as you can see in the picture - 6 wires coming out of the motor and going into the switch

Comment: See comment on previous question about checking with a competent supplier, that this one can supply a 380V motor. They will have the answer to this as well as how to connect. Otherwise, find a more competent supplier.

Comment: i am sorry what question are you reffering too ?

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/280091/how-can-i-make-my-380-380-volts-motor-to-run-on-220-volts

Comment: ah i see .. well i did, what it was advised, since the other model was not suitable. i got an inverter with the specification mentioned. the problem now is just how to wire it

Answer (score 1):

**Connect a Transformer Between VFD and Motor**

You can use a VFD that accepts 240 volts, single-phase input and provides up to 240 volts, three-phase output. You will need to connect the VFD output to a three-phase 240 to 480 volt step-up transformer. You could use three single-phase transformers. You can use a 480 to 240 volt step-down transformer and hook it up "backwards." Adjust the VFD so the output only goes up to about 190 volts.

**Connect the VFD to the Switch**

You can connect the output of the VFD to the switch. You should not operate the switch while the VFD is running, but you can use either switch setting. Using the low-speed setting will give the motor more torque and also prevent having to turn the frequency too low. The transformer may saturate, draw excessive current and overheat if the frequency is turned too low.

**Connection Diagram**

[image]

A 240:480 V 60 Hz transformer will provide some margin of safety regarding saturation of the transformer with the VFD output. A 240:480 V 50 Hz transformer will provide less margin. A 220:380 V 50 Hz transformer will provide no margin and may force you to operate the motor at a reduced voltage.

**Direct Connection To Motor**

You could connect the VFD directly to the switch if you adjust the VFD to put out 220 volts at 30 Hz. You could operate the motor up to a little more than half speed that way. You might be able to operate close to full speed with greatly reduced torque.

Comment: Will work. But don't you think a boost mode VFD would be cheaper?

Comment: i already bought this inverter "FR-S520SE 0,75K" .. i am just nt sure how to connect it

Comment: @mounim Oh, if you already have it and can't swap the motor to a 220 V one, a transformer might be the cheapest option.

Comment: @winny ... the inverter should work, i am just not sure how to wire it, since i have 6 wires from the motor

Comment: @mounim You will not be able to use the center tap arrangement with your VFD. Find which windings are used for full speed.

Comment: You keep saying that the inverter will work, but it will NOT increase the voltage to 380V. If someone told you that, they lied.

Comment: Separately, to use an inverter on a two speed motor, you permanently connect the motor for the highest speed and just run the 3 wires to it.

Comment: @J._Raefield Note that the motor is rated 0.37 kW for the low-speed connection and 0.51 kW for the high-speed connection. The torque available is 2.47 Nm at the low speed and 1.7 Nm at the high speed. Reducing the speed with the VFD will only provide 1.7 Nm at half speed while using both the VFD and the switch will provide 2.47 Nm at the low speed. This kind of motor was used because it is driving some kind of machine tool that requires increasing torque as the speed is reduced. That is why I recommended connection the VFD through the switch.

Comment: I agree with J. Raefield regarding the output voltage of the VFD. The Mitsubishi literature indicates that the nominal maximum output voltage is equal to the nominal input voltage. There is no indication that they offer a voltage boost  model. The only voltage boost VFDs I have seen advertised are 120 volt to 240 volt units.